# VBA date type mismatch

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am trying to use a vlookup function in VBA such that based on the current date it will match from with the dates in an excel worksheet and give out the corresponding values . Which would be sent through a mail. My problem is when i declare a variable  as a Date its showing type mismatch, but if it is a string its not having any problem (But i have to also enter the corresponding values in the workbook in text format).This is a bit tedious.I have been using short date in excel but could not get a clue why it is showing type mismatch.The code is mentioned below

```
Sub Send_Email_Using_VBA()
    Dim Email_Subject, Email_Send_From, Email_Send_To, _
        Email_Cc, Email_Bcc, Email_Body As String
    Dim Ldate As Date
    Dim Mail_Object, Mail_Single As Variant

    Email_Subject = "Trying to send email using VBA"
    Email_Send_From = "*****@*****.***"
    Email_Send_To = "***@****.***"
    Email_Cc = ""
    Email_Bcc = ""
    Ldate = Date
    Email_Body = Application.VLookup(Ldate, Sheet1.Range("A1:B4"), 2, False)

    On Error GoTo debugs
    Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set Mail_Single = Mail_Object.CreateItem(0)

    With Mail_Single
        .Subject = Email_Subject
        .To = Email_Send_To
        .cc = Email_Cc
        .BCC = Email_Bcc
        .Body = Email_Body
        .send
    End With
    Exit Sub

debugs:
    If Err.Description <> "" Then MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: start with [Option Explicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f.aspx) and note that Email_Subject is Variant, Email_Body is String.

Comment: `Dim LDate As String` then `LDate = CStr(Date)`?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you change Sheet1.Range("A1:B4") to Sheet1.Range("A1:B4").Value so that an array is passed to VLookup instead of a range object.

`VLookup` is a member of `WorksheetFunction` so you should change `Application.VLookup` to `WorksheetFunction.VLookup`

I used this test data:

[image: Test Data]

And the email came through by passing the range values in the vlookup

[image: email]

```
    Dim Email_Subject
    Dim Email_Send_From As String
    Dim Email_Send_To As String
    Dim Email_Cc As String
    Dim Email_Bcc As String
    Dim Email_Body As String
    Dim Mail_Object
    Dim Mail_Single As Variant

    Email_Subject = "Trying to send email using VBA"
    Email_Send_From = "*****@*****.***"
    Email_Send_To = "***@****.***"
    Email_Cc = ""
    Email_Bcc = ""

    On Error GoTo Failed_Lookup
    Email_Body = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy"), Sheet1.Range("A1:B4").Value, 2, False)

    On Error GoTo debugs
    Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set Mail_Single = Mail_Object.CreateItem(0)

    With Mail_Single
        .Subject = Email_Subject
        .To = Email_Send_To
        .cc = Email_Cc
        .BCC = Email_Bcc
        .Body = Email_Body
        .send
    End With

    Exit Sub

debugs:
    If Err.Description <> "" Then MsgBox Err.Description
    Exit Sub

Failed_Lookup:
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        MsgBox "Unable to find the date " & Date
    End If
```

Comment: i tried the above code but it is throwing the error number 1004.I am using the date format in dd-mm-yyyy and even tried the above format you have through the custom settings but its still showing the same error

Comment: Thanks for the help. can you let me know why it is not working in the dd-mm-yyyy format but working on this.Since , i am not able to use a format painter to bring into this format.

Comment: Just use Format() to get the date in the same format as what is on your worksheet. `WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Format(Ldate, "dd-mm-yyyy"), Sheet1.Range("A1:B4").Value, 2, False)`